# Create a new INI-file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function within my code which does the following:

1. creates a new ini-file to the same location path where my code is (example: C:\Users<user name>\source\repos
2. I want it to ask [username], [organisation], [server], [port] and [filename] -> save/overwrite it to path

So i want it to start like this, but I have no idea how to write it to a new file

```
### create a function that creates new file according to user input and save it to directory

def Osio8():   
    print ("Create new INI file \n")   
    
    ## asks for user input
    input_name = str(input("Give user name:" ))
    input_organization = str(input("Organisation name: "))
    input_server = str(input("Server IP address: "))
    input_port = str(input("Port number: "))
    input_file = str (input("File name:" ))
    fo = open (input_file, "w")


    ## writes the information to the file
    fo.write = multi_line_string = ("; last modified 1 April 2001 by John    Doe\n"
    "[owner]\n"
    "name=" + input_name + "\n"
    "organization=" + input_organization + "\n"
    "\n"
    "[database]\n"
    "; use IP address in case network name resolution is not working\n"
    "server=" + input_server + "\n"
    "port=" + input_port + "\n"
    "file='" + input_file + "'\n")
```

Currently this creates a new file with given file name, but nothing is stored. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import configparser

def Osio8():
    print('Create new INI file')

    input_config_file = input('Config file name: ')

    input_name = input('User name: ')
    input_organization = input('Organisation name: ')
    input_server = input('Server IP address: ')
    input_port = input('Port number: ')
    input_file = input('File name: ')

    config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config.optionxform = str

    config.add_section('owner')
    config.set('owner', '; last modified 1 April 2001 by John Doe', None)
    config['owner']['name'] = input_name
    config['owner']['organization'] = input_organization

    config.add_section('database')
    config.set('database', '; use IP address in case network name resolution is not working', None)
    config['database']['server'] = input_server
    config['database']['port'] = input_port
    config['database']['file'] = input_file

    with open(input_config_file, 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Osio8()
```

```sh
$ ./so64756020.py
Create new INI file
Config file name: newconfig.ini
User name: Test user name
Organisation name: Test org name
Server IP address: 1.2.3.4
Port number: 1234
File name: Test file name

$ cat newconfig.ini
[owner]
; last modified 1 April 2001 by John Doe
name = Test user name
organization = Test org name

[database]
; use IP address in case network name resolution is not working
server = 1.2.3.4
port = 1234
file = Test file name
```

**EDIT** (based on the comment of not being "allowed" to use `configparser`):

You will have then to create the file contents "manually" (which is fine as an exercise, but likely for nothing else beyond that).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
  
import configparser

def Osio8():
    print('Create new INI file')

    input_config_file = input('Config file name: ')

    input_name = input('User name: ')
    input_organization = input('Organisation name: ')
    input_server = input('Server IP address: ')
    input_port = input('Port number: ')
    input_file = input('File name: ')

    contents = f"""[owner]
; last modified 1 April 2001 by John Doe
name = {input_name}
organization = {input_organization}

[database]
; use IP address in case network name resolution is not working        
server = {input_server}
port = {input_port}
file = {input_file}
"""

    with open(input_config_file, 'w') as configfile:
        configfile.write(contents + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Osio8()
```

Comment: Thank you Nikolaos for the input, but for this assignment I cannot utilize config parser since it apparenly isn't allowed.

Comment: @SakariTyynelä I updated the answer. Does it serves your needs now?

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for, I truely am grateful to you, KUDOS!

Comment: @SakariTyynelä excellent, do you mind saying also "thanks" by accepting the answer :) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, ask the user for the desired file name and only after receiving an answer open a file with the desired mode ('w' probably)
If you want all the above fields before creating the file then wait with the open() until you receive all of them and only then use `open()`